# RegEx complex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write regex that checks if string:

- length is 5-15 characters long
- has at least 2 uppercase letters
- has at least 2 lowercase letters
- and has 1 digit

I appreciate any help because I am really stuck on this and don't have any ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use look ahead to check all conditions, and then match 5 to 15 characters (any), making sure there is nothing else (`^` and `$`):

[`^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=.*\d).{5,15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/hM22Yj/3)

- `^`: start of string
- `(?=  )`: positive look ahead. Does not grab any characters, but just looks ahead to see if the pattern would be matched
- `(?:  )`: make this group non-capturing, i.e. you'll not get it as capturing group that you can reference with `$1` or `\1` (language dependent)
- `.*[A-Z]`: 0 or more character(s) followed by a capital letter
- `.*[a-z]`: 0 or more character(s) followed by a lower case letter
- `.*\d`: 0 or more character(s) followed by a digit
- `{2}`: previous pattern must match twice
- `.{5-15}`: 5 to 15 characters.
- `$`: end of string

In JavaScript you can test a string against a regular expression with [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), for example:

```js
var regex = /^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=.*\d).{5,15}$/;

console.log(regex.test('a9B1c')); // false, missing capital letter
console.log(regex.test('a9B1cD')); // true
```

Comment: Thank you, I recently started to use regex and never heard or used look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

trinctot was right first, but depending on who is using your code and for what, this might be easier to maintain/modify:

```
var lowerPass = 2 <= (string.match(/[a-z]/g) || []).length;
var upperPass = 2 <= (string.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length;
var digitPass = 1 <= (string.match(/[0-9]/g) || []).length;
var lengthPass = 5 <= string.length <= 15;

var stringPass = lowerPass + upperPass + digitPass + lengthPass == 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ^([a-z]{2,}[A-Z]{2, }[0-9]{1}+) {5, 15}$
```